# How to reverse the text with js/css?

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does uʍop-ǝpısdn text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995340/how-does-uop-pisdn-text-work)

How to make the text upside down while keep the left-right order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox / Webkit:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want a solution that works most places:

```
  .verticalText
  {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: flipv fliph;
  }
```

Ultimately I ended up using a HTML5 canvas to draw vertical text in non-IE browsers due to odd results from rotating text.

Edit: Somehow I only managed to copy part of my code. Added the rest.

Comment: And it doesn't work in Opera, Safari or Iron (Chrome) either.